# How does .NET 4 decide which method to invoke when using 'dynamic' (C#) with subclasses?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, clr

I have this code snippet here:

```
class A
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

class B: A
{
    public new void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A v1 = new B();
        v1.Method();

        dynamic v2 = v1;
        v2.Method();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output is:
    A
    B

I'm trying to understand why, when using dynamic as the type for the variable v2, does B.Method() get invoked. I know that since B.Method() is declared using **new** it is a different method than A.Method(), it just has the same signature. If I declare variable v2 as a B (and do a cast) the code does what I expected, prints out B.

So why does **dynamic** make .NET treat v2 as a B and not an A?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The only piece of information available that gives a hint that `v2` should be treated as an `A` and not a `B` is the compile-time type of `v1`.  When you assign `v1` to `v2`, you're asking the runtime to discard everything that might have been known about `v2` at compile time and to figure out what `Method` refers to at runtime with no other information than the object itself, which has runtime type of `B`.

When presented with a runtime class with non-virtual hiding methods, the runtime binder could have chosen to use the least derived one instead of the most derived.  Using the most derived one fits with the "natural" use of the type; it's the same method you'd get with `var v3 = new B(); v3.Method();`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you declared v1 as Type A, you assigned it as new B(). When you assign that object instance to dynamic v2 you are assigning an in memory object of type B to that variable, so it will it still behave as a "B". If you want to access the base method you would have to cast e.g. ((A)v2).Method();